# cannot get rangfinder.js working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using rangeslider.js - http://rangeslider.js.org/

I cannot get it working, I copied the code from the demo page. I think I might be missing something!

```
<input type="range" min="1" max="3" step="1" data-rangeslider="" style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; overflow: hidden; opacity: 0;">


<div class="rangeslider rangeslider--horizontal" id="rangeslider"><div class="rangeslider__fill" style="width: 20px;"></div>
```

[Here is a codepen](http://codepen.io/jakepeg/pen/rLjOVE)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you hiding your `input[type=range]` field and recreating the HTML markup for the slider yourself? It's plugin's job to do that, isn't?

```js
// Would go to $(document).ready()
$('input[type="range"]').rangeslider();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rangeslider.js/2.1.1/rangeslider.min.js"></script>

<input
    type="range"
    min="10"
    max="1000" 
    step="10"   
    value="300" 
    data-orientation="vertical"
>
```